# Lumen Redis queue connection error. Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://xxxxxx:25061]

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, lumen

I am trying to use redis as QUEUE_CONNECTION in Lumen 8.0.

If I use the redis from the local server [127.0.0.1:6379] Then it's working fine.
But I want to use a external redis server from Digital ocean.

Here is my config in `config/queue.php`

```
'redis' => [
   'driver' => 'redis',
   'connection' => env('QUEUE_REDIS_CONNECTION', 'default'),
   'queue' => 'default',
   'retry_after' => 90,
   'block_for' => null,
   'read_write_timeout' => -1,
]
```

But I am getting this error :

[image]

I have installed these packages :

```
"predis/predis": "^1.1",
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
"illuminate/redis": "^8.25"
```

Also configured in the `.env` file like this:

```
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST="this.is.my.redis.server.ondigitalocean.com"
REDIS_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
REDIS_PORT=25061
REDIS_SCHEME=tls
```

Am I missing anything else ?

Answer (score -1):

make sure the port is allowed on the droplet's firewall.